# Responsive img with full height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to do a responsive image with the full div heigth.
In certain moment, the width stop to reduce.

The [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HJdq/)

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html,body { height:100% }
* {
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}

.teste {
height: 80%
}

.teste img {

height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="teste">
<img src="" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where are the media-queries? If it is responsive, you should add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6yuxk/)

```
 <div class="teste"> <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3782/9209525112_217d9db242_h.jpg" /></div>
```

Css

```
html,body { height:100% }
* {margin:0;
   padding: 0;}

.teste {
height: 80%
}

.teste img {
max-height: 100%;}
```